# nvidia drivers make socket fail on accept

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, pthreads, nvidia

Here is a compiling extract of a program that uses glut and pthreads.

With nvidia driver version 295 the tcp accept interrupted when glutmainloop starts (the program reports error 4)

with version 275 the program works fine.

(ubuntu, 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux problem verified also with 3.0.0-16)

Including  -lglut and -lpthread in either order does not fix the problem
if the glStuff function is not called, the program works as expected

did someone encounter similar problems?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


enum Error{WSASTARTUP,SOCKETCREATION,SOCKETBINDING,SOCKETLISTENING,SOCKETACCEPT};
void onError(Error err){
 std::cerr<<"error"<<err<<endl;
}


void* serverrun(void*){
 int mainSocket;
 int port=15002;
 struct sockaddr_in local;
 local.sin_family=AF_INET;
 local.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 local.sin_port=htons((u_short)port);
 mainSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
 int val=1;
 setsockopt(mainSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&val,sizeof(val));
 if(mainSocket<0){
  onError(SOCKETCREATION);  
}
if(bind(mainSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))!=0)
{
  onError(SOCKETBINDING);
}
if(listen(mainSocket,10)!=0)
{
  onError(SOCKETLISTENING);
} 
struct sockaddr_in from;
socklen_t fromlen=sizeof(from);

while(true){
 int cs;
 cs=accept(mainSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);
 if (cs!=-1){
  std::cout<<"new client"<<std::endl;
 }else{
   onError(SOCKETACCEPT);
 }
}//while running
return NULL;
}//run

void drawGLScene(){}

void idleFunc(){}



void glStuff(int& argc,char** argv){
 glutInit(&argc, argv);  
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);    
 glutInitWindowSize(100,100);  
 glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
 glutCreateWindow("win");
 glutDisplayFunc(drawGLScene);      
 glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
 glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: When printing the error, do not use your own error code only, also print the value of `errno`. This will tell you what the error actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be completely ignoring `errno`, what is the exact error that you see?

If it is `EINTR`, you should just retry, that's perfectly normal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was getting EINTR, and looping while errno is  EINTR fixed the problem.